# Text object A is placed on top text object B Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

As title said, I have two text object (A and B), the A is coming from database and B its writting on the report. When the report its execute, A is placed on top B. Both A and B have properties CanGrow and KeepObjectTogether.

EXEC

[image]

DESIGN

[image]

Comment: keep Text Object A in new detail section

Comment: @Mahendra I understand this approach and I tried, but its giving me blank spaces below the section and this is not wanted.

Comment: Select Fit  section

Answer (score 0):

Each object needs to be in separated section and they won't be placed one on other. So split DetailSection7 into

- DetailSection7a (place text object a there)
- DetailSection7b (place text object b there)

Comment: I understand this approach and I tried, but its giving me blank spaces below the section and this is not wanted.